# ydl.download downloading but not proceeding in code

Tags: python

Whenever I try to download a song from `youtube_dl` module (ydl) anything after it doesn't run so id do

```
ydl.download(["url"])
print('downloaded')
```

It will download the file but nothing will proceed so I won't see `downloaded` in the console

Here is the code

```
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
      ydl.download([url])
      print('downloaded')
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
      print(file)
      if file.endswith(".mp3"):
        os.rename(file,"song.mp3")
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you get error message when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you have installed [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) ?

Comment: @furas Just started getting error saying "Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found" but idk how to install ffmpeg on my server

Comment: you may have to add ffmpeg's folder to environment varariable `PATH`. You could also check in documentation if `youtube_dl` can get full path to `ffmpeg` - and then you could simply add this path.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use full path to `ffmpeg`

```
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',

    'ffmpeg_location': '/full/path/to/ffmpeg', 

    'postprocessors': [{ 
       # ... rest ...
    })
  
}
```

---

On Linux you can check location in console/terminal

```
which ffmpeg
```

Eventually you have to use command `find` to search in all folders.